# Fit a curve parallel to line segments

Tags: curve-fitting, implicit, non-linear-regression

I have a set of (2-dimensional) line segments. I want to fit a curve of second degree which is parallel to the linesegments. 
I would like to do this by using an implicit function like this: f(x,y) = a x^2 + b xy + c y^2 + d x + e y + f = 0.
I also have a couple of points where the curve should start with, so it is possible to determine f.

Here is what I tried so far:
I computed lines which are perpendicular to my line segments. Then I would like to set the gradient at the intersection point of the curve perpendicular to the lines gradient (and so equals the line segment). Unfortunately there are two problems: 1) I might have 2 solutions (intersections) 2) I do not know the intersecting points as long I don't know the coefficient of f. Eventually I get non linear equation systems which I do not know how to solve.

So far I used the singular value decomposition to solve my linear equation systems.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  [Go Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [Go Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow) To improve your question.

Comment: If you can formulate cost function, then you can use any of optimization library existing in web, like http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt for instance.